# Drilled into drywall - plastic on the drill bit

Tags: drywall

I drilled into drywall to secure a drywall anchor.  When I removed the drill there were two pieces of a plastic type material on the bit,  similar in texture to a plastic bag you get at a grocery or hardware store. Any ideas what this is before a rip a whole in the wall to figure it out?
[image: sample 1]
[image: sample 2]

Comment: That is vapour barrier.  Plastic sheeting placed on outside walls behind drywall(wall covering) to keep insulation from gaining moisture from inside houses.

Comment: If you damage the vapor barrier, then it is normally a good idea to fix it, to avoid problems down the road...

Comment: Asking how to fix the vapor barrier that you've drilled through would be the basis of a whole new question.

Comment: @freeman If the damage is just a small hole, I am not sure fixing is all that necessary. there are plenty of small holes in the exterior wall, including at the electrical outlets. If the wall has adequate insulation and the barrier is otherwise intact, why not just squirt a bunch of silicone in the hole and forget about it? What do you think?

Comment: @David that was in response to SolarMike's comment about fixing the vapor barrier as a suggestion to make it a new question and to not expect an answer in this one. That's how the Q&A format here works - 1 question per question, no worries about asking multiple questions.